# Loading xgboost regressor model but getting BoostLearner: wrong model format

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm facing this problem.

I have an xgboost Regressor model saved as a feather file as follows:

```
model.save_model(PATH_TO_MODEL)
```

and I'm trying to load the feather file as follows:

```
model = XGBRegressor()
model.load_model(model_path)
```

Unfortunately it is not working and I have been trying so many different versions but no luck.

I'm getting this error:

> XGBoostError: [06:30:35] /Users/runner/work/xgboost/xgboost/src/learner.cc:783: Check failed: fi->Read(&mparam_, sizeof(mparam_)) == sizeof(mparam_) (0 vs. 136) : BoostLearner: wrong model format
> Stack trace:
> [bt] (0) 1   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000014ebd4814 dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal() + 116
> [bt] (1) 2   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000014ec7ae46 xgboost::LearnerIO::LoadModel(dmlc::Stream*) + 2054
> [bt] (2) 3   libxgboost.dylib                    0x000000014ebce183 XGBoosterLoadModel + 419
> [bt] (3) 4   libffi.7.dylib                      0x0000000102640ead ffi_call_unix64 + 85
> [bt] (4) 5   ???                                 0x00007ffeee14bd50 0x0 + 140732892757328

Does anyone know what I can do ?

Answer (score 0):

Check model_path, your model file is empty.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31367922)